# Alyona and Copybooks: what's wrong with this code

Tags: algorithm, recursion

Here is the problem statement for Alyona and Copybooks from CodeForces # 381 (Div. 2) ([link](http://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/740/A)).

> Little girl Alyona is in a shop to buy some copybooks for school. She
>   study four subjects so she wants to have equal number of copybooks for
>   each of the subjects. There are three types of copybook's packs in the
>   shop: it is possible to buy one copybook for a rubles, a pack of two
>   copybooks for b rubles, and a pack of three copybooks for c rubles.
>   Alyona already has n copybooks.
>
> What is the minimum amount of rubles she should pay to buy such number
>   of copybooks k that n + k is divisible by 4? There are infinitely many
>   packs of any type in the shop. Alyona can buy packs of different type
>   in the same purchase.
>
> **Input** The only line contains 4 integers n, a, b, c
>   (1 ≤ n, a, b, c ≤ 109).
>
> **Output** Print the minimum amount of rubles she should pay to buy such
>   number of copybooks k that n + k is divisible by 4.

I originally attempted to solve it by exploring all of the possibilities of how to make number of textbooks divisible by 4. Let f(n) be min. cost of buying x textbooks such that (n+x)%4 = 0. Then, `f(n)=min(f(n+1)+a, f(n+2)+b, f(n+3)+c)`. The full code is below:

```
import sys
INF = sys.maxsize

def solution(n, prices):
    if n % 4 == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        ans = INF
        ans = min(solution(n + 1, prices) + prices[A],
              solution(n + 2, prices) + prices[B],
              solution(n + 3, prices) + prices[C])
        return ans
```

But, it doesn't pass all test cases. I am not sure why. What is wrong with this approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your recursive solution is actually a `3-way` recursive tree.

When `solution(3)` is called, the call stack at every step is:

`[sol(4),sol(5),sol(6)]` -> `[sol(5),sol(6)]` -> `[sol(6),sol(7),sol(8),sol(6)]` -> `[sol(7),sol(8),sol(9),sol(7),sol(8),sol(6)]` ->........

This creates memory issues like *Stack Limit exceeded*. Please remove recursion from here. You can modify your solution to something like:

```
def solution(n,prices):
  if n%4==0:
    return 0
  rem = 4-(n%4)
  if rem==1:
    return min(prices[0],prices[1]+prices[2],3*prices[2])
  elif rem==2:
    return min(2*prices[0], prices[1], 2*prices[2])
  else:
    return min(3*prices[0],prices[0]+prices[1],prices[2])
```

Hope it helps!!!

**Edit:** I modified your recursive solution to kill the unending recursion.

```
import sys
INF = sys.maxsize

def solution(n, prices, k):
    if k>10:
        return INF
    if n % 4 == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        ans = min(solution(n + 1, prices,k+1) + prices[0],
              solution(n + 2, prices,k+2) + prices[1],
              solution(n + 3, prices,k+3) + prices[2])
        return ans

def main():
  n,a,b,c = map(int, raw_input().split())
  prices = [a,b,c]
  print solution(n,prices,0)

main()
```

Comment: Good. The approach was correct, though more complex than need be. The edited version with infinite recursion removed passed all test cases.